# How can I show/hide div using Java Script on click of button

Tags: javascript, onclick, show-hide, forms, buttonclick

I am trying to write a PHP Java Script, but struggling to write in this section of coding.

I am trying to make a buttom in form in  that opens

The code I have written so far is

```
function display(e){
    if (e.clicked)
        document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
    else
        document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'block';
```

and the FORM CODE is;

```
 <input type="button" value=" Book Now " onClick="display(this)"/></input>
```

any help to point out my clear mistakes would be great, the live code can be seen at
http://affordablecleaners.co.uk/quote/

Thanks,

Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something similar to the following

```
var i = 0;
var display = function() {
    document.getElementById('2').style.display = (i++ % 2) ? "none" : "block";
};
```

Essentially, we're creating a variable `i` and increasing it by one every time the function is called. If, when the function is called, `i` is an even number, then we set it to `display: block`. Otherwise, set it to `display: none`.

The biggest downside to this solution is cluttering the global scope. If this is an issue, you can also do the following.

```
var display = function() {
    document.getElementById('2').style.display = (document.getElementById('2').style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
};
```

Comment: ooh, I like this, let me try it now

Comment: but wait, i think it needs to be ? "none" : "block"; as I want it to be hidden unless clicked

Comment: Oh, sorry. If you want it to be shown the first time it's clicked, change it to either `i = 1` or just change the statements (`? "none" : "block"`). Updated

Comment: hmm.. what is my onclick= ??? do i need to assign a function name to the javescript?

Comment: `onclick="display()"`, or assign this in the javascript.

Comment: one problem now, when I click once it does nothing, but double click it hides. Can't hide at begining.

Try an http://affordablecleaners.co.uk/quote/

Please advise,

Thanks

Comment: WE GOT IT GUYS !!!!! AWSOME

DIDN'T HAVE THE //
style="display:none;">

Thanks so much for your help.

Is it possible to add a variable, so that it will only open when value TV>0?

Comment: sure, but I dont know what you're talking about. Also, please dont put the `style="display:none"` inline. It was only inline on the example page to show exactly what you'd need.

Comment: the end value in a calculation, shall I create a new question for this??

Comment: No... This seems extremely basic. Please read some Javascript tutorials. Before that, though, read w3fools.com

Comment: Ok, cheers nile, I never use Javascript only HTML and PHP, so Its more or less trial and error when I get into the relms of Javascript haha. Thanks for all your help, same to everyone else on this question, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here's the (untested) logic...

```
function display(state, which){

if (state==1) {document.getElementById(which).style.display ='none';}

    else

    {document.getElementById(which).style.display = 'block';}
}
```

and then in your button...

to turn ON

```
onclick="display('1',someDIV)"
```

to turn OFF

```
onclick="display('0',someDIV)"
```

Comment: can you have a double on click for one button?

Comment: This one is a toggle but you can use the L-Click for ON and R-Click for OFF if you want. Would you like that?

Comment: I don't know how to handle double clicks if that's what you meant.

Comment: He wants to get rid of your state argument and have that be automatic within one click. He wants it to be an automatic toggle, basically... my script does that, though.